# Filter sumproduct formula based on array

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Given Table 1, I am able to calculate the sum of the revenue with the `SUMPRODUCT` formula. Though, I would like to be able to filter out specific areas directly in the formula. The formula listed below gives the correct result `(13,000)` when area B is filtered out of the data with:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sales[Area]<>Exceptions[Area]);Sales[Quantity];Sales[Price per unit])`

However, when I add another area in Table 2, the formula returns an error. Is it possible to filter out multiple variables (areas) directly in the formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISERROR(MATCH())`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(MATCH(Sales[Area];Exceptions[Area];0)));Sales[Quantity];Sales[Price per unit])
```

`--(ISERROR(MATCH(Sales[Area];Exceptions[Area];0)))` will return 1 if the area is not found in the search area, because the MATCH will return an error when it is not found in the list.

[image]